# Scala: Apply same function to 2 lists in one call

Tags: scala, scalaz

let say I have

```
val list: List[(Int, String)] = List((1,"test"),(2,"test2"),(3,"sample"))
```

I need to partition this list in two, based on (Int, String) value. So far, so good. 
For example it can be

```
def isValid(elem: (Int, String)) = elem._1 < 3 && elem._2.startsWith("test")
val (good, bad) = list.partition(isValid)
```

So, now I had 2 lists with signatures List[(Int, String)], but I need only Int part(some id). Off course I can write some function

```
def ids(list:List(Int, String)) = list.map(_._1)
```

and call it on both lists

```
val (ok, wrong) = (ids(good), ids(bad))
```

it worked, but looks little bit boilerplate. I prefer something like

```
val (good, bad) = list.partition(isValid).map(ids)
```

But it obviously not possible. So is there "Nicer" way to do what I need? 
I understand that it's not so bad, but feel that there exist some functional pattern or general solution for such cases and I want to know it:) Thanks!

P.S. Thanks for all! Finally it's transformed to

```
private def handleGames(games:List[String], lastId:Int) = {
  val (ok, wrong) = games.foldLeft(
  (List.empty[Int], List.empty[Int])){
    (a, b) => b match {
      case gameRegex(d,w,e) => {
        if(filterGame((d, w, e), lastId)) (d.toInt :: a._1, a._2)
        else (a._1, d.toInt :: a._2 )
      }
      case _ => log.debug(s"not handled game template is: $b"); a
    }
  }
  log.debug(s"not handled game ids are: ${wrong.mkString(",")}")
  ok
}
```

Comment: Honestly, I'd just use the two `map`s, unless there's a performance problem. Then I'd use the `fold`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for a `foldLeft` on the `List`:

```
myList.foldLeft((List.empty[Int], List.empty[Int])){
  case ((good, bad), (id, value)) if predicate(id, value) => (id :: good, bad)
  case ((good, bad), (id, _)) => (good, id :: bad)
}
```

This way you're operating at every stage doing both a transform and an accumulate. The returned type will be `(List[Int], List[Int])` assuming `predicate` is the function which chooses between "good" and "bad" states. The cast of the `Nil` is due to the aggressive nature of Scala for choosing the most restrictive type on a foldl.

Comment: Thanks, wheaties. I agree with you, it is more functional. However, I think it is those rare case when pure functional style is less readable, probably I'll go with my code...

Comment: I'll change to using `empty` then. Maybe that'll be more readable?

Comment: Well, it's better, but casts  to Nil wasn't most complicated thing. After some thinking I used your suggestion(but it's more comlicated then I asked previously). I chosen it, mostly because in that case it is only one pass over collection, however I still don't glad with syntax. I'll add final code to question

Answer (score 1):

An additional approach using Cats can be used with `Tuple2K` and `Foldable`s `foldMap`. Note this requires help from the [kind-projector](https://github.com/non/kind-projector) compiler plugin

```
import cats.implicits._
import cats.Foldable
import cats.data.Tuple2K

val listTuple = Tuple2K(list, otherList)
val (good, bad) = Foldable[Tuple2K[List, List, ?]].foldMap(listTuple)(f =>
  if (isValid(f)) (List(f), List.empty) else (List.empty, List(f)))
```

Comment: You should caveat that with the fact that you're also using the type projector plugin. That's non-standard Scala syntax in the type parameters of `Foldable`.

Comment: It is interesting, but it is even more complicated to people who has OOP past. I am trying to use functional constructs wherever I can, but in such cases I prefer  to go with straightforward code